# integral inequality: midpoint of interval vs. expectation over interval

Tags: integration, inequality

I have been thinking about an inequality that should be self-evident, but which I have difficulties proving formally. It looks like the following:

Take a function $f(x)$ with $f'(x)>0$ and scalars $a,b$, where $b > a$, then 
\begin{equation}
\int_a^bxf(x)dx > \frac{a + b}{2}\int_a^bf(x)dx. 
\end{equation}

I have tried to relate this to the inequalities I know but without success. Can you provide a proof or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? For example take $f(x) = \log x, a = 0 , b = 1$. The LHS evaluates to $-\dfrac{1}{4}$ while the RHS is $-\dfrac{1}{2}$. Maybe you are also assuming that $f(x) > 0$ in $(a,b)$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 isn't that improper at $a=0$?

Comment: Well, the integral is defined if you take the limit. However, to avoid that just take the case $f(x) = x^2 - 1$ with the same limits. The inequality would still fail since the function is negative.

Comment: Well, almost.  Your new example has $f'(x)=0$ at $a=0$.  OP claims $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This statement is correct when all conditions are fulfilled; see answer. It would be nice of the contributors not to downvote questions when there is no concrete evidence that the claim is wrong.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg that’s not why people downvoted this.  It was likely lack of effort, work, background, or context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(x)>0$ then f is increasing and it is true that for any $a<t<x$, $f(a)<f(t)<f(x)$.

Now integrate the above inequality with respect to t:

$$(x-a)f(a)<\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{dt}<(x-a)f(x)$$

Integrate again with respect to x in the interval $[a,b]$:

$$\int_{a}^b(x-a)f(a)\mathrm{dx}<\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{dt}\,\mathrm{dx}<\int_{a}^b(x-a)f(x)\mathrm{dx}$$

However we find by integration by parts on the double integral that:

$$\int_{a}^b (x)'\left(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{dt}\right)\mathrm{dx}=b\int_{a}^bf(x)\mathrm{dx}-\int_a^bxf(x)\mathrm{dx}$$

and so considering the rightmost inequality we conclude that:

$$b\int_{a}^bf(x)\mathrm{dx}-\int_a^bxf(x)\mathrm{dx}<\int_{a}^b xf(x)\mathrm{dx}-a\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{dx}\\\Rightarrow\quad\int_{a}^bxf(x)\mathrm{dx}>\frac{a+b}{2}\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{dx}$$

as instructed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But shouldn't the integral in the middle term of the second equation read $\int_a^b\int_a^x f(t)dtdx$?

Comment: Why does it matter where I put the differential? It's a matter of personal taste and I usually put in a place where it's clear in what order the integrals have to be performed.